# Character array weirdness

Tags: array

I'm using Energia to program one of TI's MCU. Since Energia is based off the Arduino IDE, I'm hoping someone can help me here.

I'm building a simple UDP packet sender and receiver app. The MCU starts up and connects to the local Wifi network and waits for a packet from another device on the same network.

This packet is collected in a char array `char packetBuffer[16];`

I want to split this array into two separate arrays each of 8 elements. These are `char lampCmdRead[8];` and `char pwdReadBuffer[8];` Now the network bit works great. I can send the packet through my desktop and receive it on the MCU. However when I split this array I see that the `pwdReadBuffer` shows the same contents as `packetBuffer` even though they are of different sizes. How is this possible?

Here is the code:

```
char packetBuffer[16];
char lampCmdRead[8];
char pwdReadBuffer[8];

// This is code from the 'void loop()' section
int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();

if(packetSize) {
 int len = Udp.read(packetBuffer, 16);
 if (len > 0) packetBuffer[len] = 0;
 Serial.println();

 Serial.println("packetBuffer:");
 Serial.println(packetBuffer);
 Serial.println();

 for(ctr = 0; ctr < 8; ctr++) {
   pwdReadBuffer[ctr] = packetBuffer[ctr];
 }
 if (len > 8) pwdReadBuffer[len] = 0;

 for(ctr = 0; ctr < 8; ctr++) {
   lampCmdRead[ctr] = packetBuffer[ctr+8];
 }    
 if (len > 8) lampCmdRead[len] = 0;

 Serial.println("pwdReadBuffer:");
 Serial.println(pwdReadBuffer);
 Serial.println();

 Serial.println("lampCmdRead:");
 Serial.println(lampCmdRead);
 Serial.println();
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Received packet of size 16
From 192.168.1.101, port 55056

packetBuffer:
2qZ@X51Rredledon

pwdReadBuffer:
2qZ@X51Rredledon

lampCmdRead:
redledon
```

Comment: You're overflowing your buffers.

Comment: Also you're not terminating your strings properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (len > 8) pwdReadBuffer[len] = 0;
```

This line is unsafe.  You declared pwdReadBuffer to be only 8 bytes in size, but this line of code will either do nothing, or write *outside* of the target buffer, with unpredictable results.

You make a related mistake here:

```
if (len > 8) lampCmdRead[len] = 0;
```

First the test should be `>=` but again, such a value would be beyond the end of the target buffer.

Also consider that if you receive 8 or more characters, you will have no room for a terminating null in pwdReadBuffer, and so cannot pass it to anything that expects a null terminated string.

If you want to use null-terminate storage for a string of up to 8 bytes size, you need 9 bytes of storage.  And of course you need to only use in-range indices to access the elements.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior (where contents of `pwdReadBuffer` print out the same as those of `packetBuffer`) is occurring because you haven't properly null-terminated your strings.

After you copy the first 8 characters of `packetBuffer` to `pwdReadBuffer` the statement `if (len > 8) pwdReadBuffer[len] = 0;` gets executed.  It sets `pwdReadBuffer[16]` to 0, ie, references out of array bounds.

Apparently `lampCmdRead` is allocated directly after `pwdReadBuffer`, so when you copy the next 8  characters of `packetBuffer` to `lampCmdRead`, they are being copied, in effect, to `pwdReadBuffer[8] ... pwdReadBuffer[15]`, so that the `println` prints a 16-character string,
`2qZ@X51Rredledon`.

For each of your three arrays, allocate an extra byte for a null terminator.